# iOS 15 beta 6 tab bar issue

Tags: ios, safari, sticky, tabbar, beta

I would like to fix an issue I have on my website. I would like to have the safe bottom area the same color than the tab bar when scrolling, instead of the body background. What would you suggest me to do?

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: var(--black-3);
    z-index: 9;
}
```

First screen

[image]

Second screen

[image]

Comment: In order to assist you, please provide more details regarding the way you created you site. Are you using a framework? html, bootstrap...
Show us the code as well if you have it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added the CSS code I use for the tab bar component (".header" in CSS)

Answer (score 1):

Safari changing the tab/status bar color dynamically is a new feature of Safari 15. The release also adds support for the `theme-color` meta tag for customizing the color. From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15-beta-release-notes):

> - Added support for the `theme-color` meta tag to change the tab bar background and over-scroll area in macOS and iPadOS, and the status bar in iOS.

You have to put the `<meta name="theme-color" content="#xxxxxx">` tag to your web page to use a specific color instead of the automatically picked one. Unfortunately this also means you can’t use your CSS variable for it but have to define the colour value in at least two places now.

Keep in mind that this also sets the top bar color for Chrome Android and the tab bar is at top in macOS and iPadOS Safari, so the effect may not be expected. The meta tag supports media queries in `media` attribute (see the release notes link) and changing the `content` attribute’s value using javascript should work as expected though (demonstrated in the Apple Developers video in references).

Note that `content` attribute accepts a CSS `<color>`. This means that the following is possible:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]").content =
    window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".header"))
      .getPropertyValue("background-color");
});
```

I don’t have a device with Safari 15 beta available to test with, but I suppose you could also add the element dynamically. It works with Chrome Android at least:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  let meta = document.createElement("meta");
  meta.name = "theme-color";
  meta.content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".header"))
                         .getPropertyValue("background-color");
  document.head.appendChild(meta);
});
```

**Resources:**

- [MDN: Standard metadata names: theme-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color)
- [CSS-Tricks: Meta Theme Color and Trickery](https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/)
- [Apple Developers: Design for Safari 15](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10029/) (`theme-color` is featured in the first part of the video. It also has information about using the safe area environment variables for content floating at bottom.

**Edit:** Added the javascript examples

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately yes, I would like to be able to do that :

<meta name="theme-color" content="<?php echo get_field( 'tabbar_color' )"> instead of <meta name="theme-color" content="#xxxxxx">

But it seems not possible

Comment: How about `document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]").content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".header")).getPropertyValue("background-color")` **Edit:** just noticed your edit. What prevents using the PHP code? Does it return `var(--black-3)`?

Comment: I tried using `<meta name="theme-color" content="<?php echo get_field( 'tabbar_color' )">` but it keeps using automatic picking color (background-page color instead of tab-bar color).

Where am I supposed to add your code ? In my header.php ?

Comment: All `meta` tags go inside the `head` element. Note that you can’t use CSS variables in `content` so if your PHP code returns `var(--black-3)`, it will not work. Added javascript example to my answer.